# Mouseenter mouseleave

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток! Есть код:

```
$('document').on('mouseenter', '.sel1', function(){$('.sel2').show()})
$('document').on('mouseleave', '.sel1', function(){$('.sel2').hide()})
```

Почему блок .sel2 моргает, когда я вожу курсором по .sel1?  
Если выводить в консоль инфу, то события выполняются один раз и последовательно.
А если написать show('slow'), то блок появится/исчезнет/появится при событии mouseenter

Answer (score 1):

> Если выводить в консоль инфу, то события выполняются один раз и последовательно.
> А если написать show('slow'), то блок появится/исчезнет/появится при событии mouseenter

Вы, наверноек, рушите логику выведнием в консоль (без кода сказать сложно), потому что второй случай - это нормальное поведение jQuery. При вызове show(n)/hide(n) элемент не скрывается/показывается немедленно, а в *очередь эффектов данного элемента добавляется соответсвующая анимация* (sic!). Вам нужно использовать методы .stop() или .dequeue(), чтобы удалить из очередь(-и) анимации. Также можно использовать несколько очередей (по умолчанию используется очередь fx), но это уже не относится к обсуждению.